# How to identify the completion status of a ProgressMonitor in Eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have an Eclipse plugin that performs various operations on a given project. Before starting the operation the plugin always does a refresh of the project to make sure that the project is in sync. For that i use project.refreshLocal(IProject.DEPTH_INFINITE, monitor).

Here i defined my own progress monitor that implements IProgressMonitor and use the done() method to know when the refresh task is complete. It was working fine with Eclipse 3.x. Now i switched to 4.11 and unfortunately the done() method is not called back by the project.refreshLocal. :(

```
// Part of ProgressMonitor Implementation
public class SimpleProgressMonitor implements IProgressMonitor {
    private boolean cancelled = false;
    private boolean complete = false;

    public void done() {
        complete = true;
    }

    public void setCanceled(boolean value) {
        cancelled = value;
    }

    // Method i use to check if progress monitor is set to done or cancelled
    public void waitForCompletion() {
        while(!complete && !cancelled) {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the done method to be called but is not called by the Eclipse's refresh Job. Please help me on how to identify if the progress monitor has been notified of the task completion.

Comment: `refreshLocal` doesn't return until the refresh is complete so I don't see why you need that. Also you should **never** call `Thread.sleep` in the UI thread. If you want to do the refresh asynchronously use a `WorkspaceJob` and use a job listener to listen for the job completing.

Comment: Hi greg, thanks for your input. I will check the WorkspaceJob. refreshLocal is just one example where i use the progress monitor but there are other cases. So in general is there any way to track the completion of my own progress monitor? Not: The job that uses this progress monitor is not my implementation, so i can't call done method.

Comment: Just about everything that uses a progress monitor completes synchronously, I don't think there is ever a need to do a wait like this.

Comment: If you're the one implementing an `IProgressMonitor`, rather than just using one like the `NullProgressMonitor`, the things you're asking about are for you to also implement. You're missing some methods that should be required, the ones like `beginTask` and `worked` which is where your monitor would be given the numbers to make those calculations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time guys. I'm skipping the progress monitor completion check now. it works perfect. But not sure why the call was not made though.

Answer (score 0):

The approach to wrap monitor to listen for subtask completion looks strange in general. 
Please try to use `org.eclipse.core.runtime.SubMonitor` instead.

If you need notifications from a `org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.Job` instance you can use `org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.IJobChangeListener`.